# regular expression: trying to include unlimited whitespaces for any words in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
[RegularExpression(@"\S*[a-z\s]\S*\s*", ErrorMessage = "Please add 
category name letters only")]
```

This works fine if I input some words something like this...test test. But if I try to do this... test test test, I will get the ErrorMessage that I implemented. The thing is that I don't know how many words are going to put in by the end user. Is there a way where unlimted whitespaces could put in place? Could some tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance. I am using VS2010

Comment: I don't understand. Do you think that you could restate the rule(s) for me?  What do you want to allow, and what to disallow?

Comment: What format do you want exactly? Only lower-case letters? Any starting or ending requirements? How many spaces between words? No idea what you need it for but IMHO a category name ending with space sounds strange. You should `exactly` state what is allowed and what is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z\s]{1,})
```

use regex from above to resolve your problem.
Baically a-zA-Z will match any word case insensitive, and \s will match any whitespace character and {1,} will tell that this combination needs to have one or any number of matches.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Senad Meskin exactly what I was looking. Most Appreicated.